# How to remove an item in an array by its id

Tags: reactjs, inertiajs

I have a problem to remove specific data inside an array by id. I get a hint in google using `filter()`is the best way to remove the element like code bellow.

lets say i have data like bellow

```
   const [cart,setCart] = useState([{id:1,name:shirt,qty:1},{id:1,name:t-shirt,qty:1}])
```

then i have a function to remove the item inside array

```
const removeCartItem = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let id = e.target.id;//the id needed to remove the data
    setCart((cart) =>
        cart.filter((item) => item.id !== id)
    );

}
```

this not working so i need your help because i dont familiar with react js
thankyou in advance

Comment: Instead of mutating the `cart` directly, I would say you should just simply memoize the filtered array as `const filteredCart = useMemo(FILTER_LOGIC_HERE)`. This is so you don't end up mutating your single source of truth.

Comment: Thankyour for giving me new knowlegdge i will try using useMemo

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @SuleymanSah removing data from the array

Comment: Is it because your data has duplicate id values? In your example both id's are same 1. Also can you `console.log(e.target.id)` to check whether the id is correct.

Comment: I created a sandbox to show a working example of this. I think @SuleymanSah is right. Either the `target.id` is undefined, or it is a string. `item.id != id` would work if it's a string, but it is probably the wrong approach. https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-river-tkqjzw?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @StuartNichols ok let me try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, you need to convert the id obtained from e.target.id to a number before performing the comparison. You can use the parseInt function for this purpose. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
  const removeCartItem = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const id = parseInt(e.target.id, 10); // Convert id to a number
      setCart((cart) =>
        cart.filter((item) => item.id !== id)
      );
    };
```

Now, the comparison item.id !== id will work correctly, and the item with the matching id will be removed from the cart array.

Make sure that the id you're passing to the removeCartItem function is the correct id of the item you want to remove.

Comment: Most or all of your six answers in the last few hours appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.